# Get a certain combination from two list of strings

Tags: vb.net

This problem hunts me for over a month.
It goes like this :
We have two list of strings

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c", "d"} ' and so on
Dim List2 As New List(Of String) From {"e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"} ' and so on
```

At this point we have 24 possible combinations (List1 with List2)

```
Dim allCombo As Integer = List1.Count * List2.Count
```

Looping and storing all the possible combinations is not an option.
Now what kind of math calculation can I apply so that if I want the combination number 13 , to return 'c' with 'e' ; or 24 which is 'd' with 'j' and so on.
I am stuck on this, can someone help me please ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: In your example, C is index 2 and E is index 0, so how does 13 play into it?

Comment: `Dim element13 = List1.SelectMany(Function(a) List2.Select(Function(b) a & b)).ElementAt(13)`  it will be `cf` though.  Not sure why all possible combinations is not an option.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger , my mistake , I am aware of that ! Did not do the -1 , but its ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Function GetIndex(index As Integer) As String
    Dim List1 As New List(Of String) From {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    Dim List2 As New List(Of String) From {"e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"}

    Dim intIndex0 As Integer = index - 1 'convert to 0-based
    Dim index1 As Integer = intIndex0 \ List2.Count 'integer division
    Dim index2 As Integer = intIndex0 Mod List2.Count 'modulo (remainder)
    Return List1(index1) & List2(index2)
  End Function
```

Comment: OK , now i see my mistake , cause I was doing index2 the wrong way ! Thank you ! +1

Comment: You're welcome. The maths is the same as iterating through every cell of a two-dimensional grid (e.g. List1 might be the rows and List 2 could be the columns). Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim L1 = "abcd"   ' 4
    Dim L2 = "efghij" ' 6

    Dim i = 13
    Dim indexInL1 = (i - 1) \ L2.Length    ' 12  \  6 = 2 
    Dim indexInL2 = (i - 1) Mod L2.Length  ' 12 Mod 6 = 0

    Dim result = L1(indexInL1) & L2(indexInL2) ' "ce"
```